# How to check a string for a character?

Tags: string, actionscript-3

I would like to find out how often a dot is in a string.
I tried the function below but it shows 11 instead of 1.

```
trace(count("example.com", "."));

function count(s:String, letter:String)
{
    return s.match(new RegExp(letter,"g")).length;
}
```

What is wrong with the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In regular expressions, the `.` means "any character". Replace it with `\.`

If you are writing a general function, you have to make sure that the expression you pass to the `RegExp` is in fact looking for the thing you think you are looking for. If it's only ever a single character, I believe you can safely "escape" it by putting a `\` in front of it.